# How can I change CMD to CTRL in Linux Mint only in Terminal?

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, control-characters

I installed Linux Mint on my MacBook Air, and I prefer to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> for copying/pasting, opening and closing windows, and general things like that. However, I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to input to the Terminal. So, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would terminate whatever command I'm running, and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would copy any text that's highlighted. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I just did this myself in Linux Mint 20.2, Cinnamon, 64-bit.

Procedure:

1. Open Terminal
2. Click on `Edit` (in the menu bar at the top).
3. Click on `Preferences`
4. Click on `Shortcuts`
5. Double click on the shortcut you wish to change, then press the new key combination you want to use. For example, to replace copy double click on where it says <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on your keyboard.

NOTE: I had to disable the Clock app from opening, which was already mapped to <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> by default, otherwise it conflicts with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for Terminal Copy and it will not work.

How to disable Clock app from opening with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>:

1. Right click on your clock in your panel (lower right hand corner).
2. Left click on `Configure`...
3. Double left click on Super + C
4. You can now reassign the clock app to open with whatever keyboard shortcut you want, or you can simply remove the keyboard shortcut entirely by pressing the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key (or the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, as was true on my keyboard).

Hope this helps, and have fun with the keyboard shortcuts! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a satisfactory* solution built in to system settings within **Linux Mint** by enabling the following options under:

`Keyboard` > `Layouts` > `Options...`

**Ctrl position**:

- Swap Left Alt with Left Ctrl
- Swap Left Win with Left Ctrl
- Swap Right Win with Right Ctrl

[image]

*Doesn't map identical to the macOS keyboard layout for <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but it's pretty close for the most common operations one does with their left hand on the Mac.